# How to convert int value into string on jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have a map that contains Map , which i iterate it on jsp page using

```
    <c:forEach var="schoolDetails" items="${schoolCodeIdMap}"> 
                                                  //below i am getting value from another map which contains String as a key.     
    <c:set var="smsStatsCalendar" value="${smsStats.get(schoolDetails.value)}"></c:set>

<c:foreach>
```

In above code smsStats contains String as key and I am passing Integer Value to get object. How can i convert That schoolDetails.value (int) value into string to get object.

Answer (score 7):

You could set it to another variable using `c:set`, which should do implicit String conversion for you:

```
<c:forEach var="schoolDetails" items="${schoolCodeIdMap}"> 
    <c:set var="detailValue">${schoolDetails.value}</c:set>
    <c:set var="smsStatsCalendar" value="${smsStats.get(detailValue)}"/>
<c:foreach>
```

The body of a `c:set` tag will always be interpretted as plain text, and so get converted to a `String` variable by the tag. This is in contrast to using:

```
<c:set var="detailValue" value="${schoolDetails.value}"/>
```

which would maintain the property type as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the integer to string separately and then using it where you want.

Other way (not completely sure) is to append an empty String before the integer, so it will return a new string, like this;

```
int a = 10;
```

Now  `""+a` will represent a String.