# How to get a value from a map<string, string> in .jsp - I can print the entire map, but can't pull individual values from it

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm serving a model and view with Spring 3.0.5 and JSP.

I have a form backing object, lets call it 'myCommandObject' and it has a map as a property - tempMap.

As I'm serving the model and view, if I debug my java, I can see the map, in the model, ready to be served:

```
LinkedHashMap<K,V> | tempMap | {432345=Other - please comment, 123534=first option, 21331=second option, 234634=third option, 234444=Please Select One}
```

In my JSP, I can display the entire map from the model by doing the following:

```
    <c:out value="MARK"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="MARK"></c:out>
```

and when the view is rendered in my browser as HTML I see :

```
MARK 432345=Other - please comment, 123534=first option, 21331=second option, 234634=third option, 234444=Please Select One MARK
```

I can also fetch and display one of these key-values that are shown above like:

```
        <c:out value="${otherObj.uid}"></c:out>
```

and I see displayed a value such as:

```
 123534
```

(though this changes dynamically - so I can't just hard code the value)

However, no matter *how* I try to pull individual values from my map - I get nothing but blanks and error messages back.

How can I display a single value form this map using JSP?

**What I've tried:**

```
<c:out value="${tempMap[otherObj.uid]}"></c:out>


 <c:out value="${tempMap[${otherObj.uid]} }"></c:out>


<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap}"></c:out>


<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap['otherObj.uid']}"></c:out>


<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap['otherObj.uid']}"></c:out>


<c:set var="varName" value="${otherObj.uid}"/>
<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap[varName]}"></c:out>


<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap(otherObj.uid)}"></c:out>
```

All of these just result in blank output - except the last one which throws an EL exception.

What am I doing wrong? how do I pull a value out of a map with JSP?

Comment: What do you have in this object otherObj.uid ? probable its value is different from the others in the map.

Comment: What is the type of `otherObj.uid`?

Comment: `otherObj.uid` has to be of the exact same type as the keys of `myCommandObject.tempMap`. In that case `<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap[otherObj.uid]}"/>` should work.

Comment: @reos Yep, they're the same value, I can print the key (otherobject.uid) out alongside where I'm trying to print the map value, and it works fine.

Comment: @Roman the map is of type <string, string>, and otherobject.uid is of type long - but i understand that assigning it to a variable as in my 6th example should cast it to a string type for me? That and all my variations of it didn't help either..... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it working.

As the commentors are pointing out - the problem is one of type conversion.

I'm using a Long type key on a Map, and no implicit type conversion takes place using this syntax.

I *thought* I was trying explicit type conversion in several of my examples, using the trick in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501475/how-to-convert-int-value-into-string-on-jsp-page) stack overflow question...however I misread the example and was doing it wrong.

This was wrong:

```
<c:set var="varName" value="${otherObj.uid}"/>
<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap[varName]}"></c:out>
```

This is what worked:

```
<c:set var="varName">${otherObj.uid}</c:set>
<c:out value="${myCommandObject.tempMap[varName]}"></c:out>
```

The *body* of a < c:set > tag is always interpreted as a string and assigned to the variable - but if you give it a 'value' property, the type of the var remains whatever it was evaluated as in the expression... intuitive, I know.